# How to make a JTable sort not on the event thread?

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable

So I have an expensive sort that can use IO or grabbing data from the net to help it sort.

My problem is that JTable sort is on the event thread and therefore freezes the GUI.

How do I change it so it doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did have a solution which I forgot to post. But still wasn't perfect, so in the end I just used a table library.

Glazed lists is quite good in dealing with sorting and viewing large sets of data:
http://www.glazedlists.com/

Answer (score 2):

Since Java 6, there's the `RowSorter` interface. I haven't dealt with it myself, but it looks as though it should be possible to implement it asynchronously and notify the table when it's done (or that may even already be its default behaviour).

Comment: That's a start in the right direction. Currently I'm using TableRowSorter. Is there any example code or libraries that help in this area?

Answer (score 0):

You can start a new Thread and pass a anonymous Runnable instance:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {


        public void run() {
            //Sort the JTable
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't help me. I don't sort the table manually.